# Нужно ли обособлять?

Tags: пунктуация

***Не то(,) чтобы я / Я не то(,) чтобы*** этого не знал(,) — мне просто в голову не пришло, что он мог вдруг вспомнить об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Между частями выражения «не то чтобы» знаки препинания не ставятся. 
Он не то чтобы к славе стремился – // просто жил, искушая судьбу... Б. ***Окуджава, Полдень в деревне***
За дорогой не то чтоб пустыня – // но пейзаж без домов и людей. ***Б. Окуджава, Полдень в деревне.***

> Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж!) Мне тоже не хотелось ставить в этом случае. Наконец-то угадал!)